# Difference between applying async-await at client and at service

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await

I have created a WCF service and have its operationcontract and implementation like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetName(string name);

   public async Task<string> GetName(string name)
    {
         await Task.Delay(5000);
         var task1 = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
             return "Your name is : " + name;
         });
         var result = await task1;
         return result;
        }
```

Now i am using this service at client side and created the client.

```
 ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```

It shows be 2 methods for my implementation: GetName and GetNameAsync

I can use the following two ways to access the service.

```
var result_GetName = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.GetName("My Input"));
 var result_GetNameAsync = await client.GetNameAsync("My Input");
```

- Q.1 Is there any difference between the two approaches?
- Q.2 Is it recommended to use one of them in particular condition? or i can use any of them at any time.
- Q.3 For the second call i am using async-await at two places (client-server), is there any advantage of it?

Please guide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what the generated code looks like for WCF, but I'd *expect* the second form to be better. (EDIT: Read [Stephen's blog post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html) for details of why this is true.)

The first approach creates a new task which calls the method *synchronously* - blocking a thread for as long as it takes for the method to return. So if you have lots of those calls concurrently, you'll end up using a lot of threads and therefore memory.

I'd *expect* the second approach to be more "natively" asynchronous - basically sending the request and then handling the response on a potentially different thread when it comes back.

For your final question:

> For the second call i am using async-await at two places (clien-server), is there any advantage of it?

You're using `await` in two places in *both* snippets. But yes, there's definitely an advantage in using asynchronous code in both places. In the client, you're saving client threads. In the server, you're saving server threads.

Using the purely asynchronous version, you could have hundreds of calls from a client to a server, without using more than one or two threads in each of those processes. In the client, you don't have anything blocked, waiting for the response - you just have continuations ready to be called when the response comes through. In the server, you don't have anything blocked on a `Thread.Sleep` call (the logical synchronous equivalent of `Task.Delay`) - you just have a lot of continuations ready to run when the delay expires.

So yes, it's good on each side. You get the benefit wherever you're using it, basically.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon. I am aware about the responsiveness advantage of using the async-await. Your answer clearly explains the scalability advantage. Minimum resources will get used by using the asycn on both client and server side. Again thanks for your reply.

Comment: The new `*Async` methods on the client proxy are "natively asynchronous". I wrote a blog post on the [`async` updates to WCF](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary: Thanks for the confirmation. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Please comment on this question as i've put together whatever i've understood from ur answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673650/real-advantages-of-async-await#comment17103260_12673650