# Does Entity Framework support parallel async queries?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What happens when we start multiple async Entity Framework queries and **run them in parallel?**

Are they physically executed in parallel? Are they serialized by Entity Framework? Is this unsupported? Does it result in an exception?

```
public async Task QueryDatabase()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        Task task1 = context.SomeTable1.ToListAsync();
        Task task2 = context.SomeTable2.ToListAsync();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41749896/ef-6-how-to-correctly-perform-parallel-queries

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is not supported as per the [specifications of version 6](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.#ThreadSafety).

This should throw a `DbConcurrencyException` exception saying

> **A second operation started on this context before a previous
> asynchronous operation completed.** Use 'await' to ensure that any
> asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
> on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
> safe.
>
> EF will **detect** if the developer attempts to execute two async operations at one time **and throw**.

From [a codeplex page of the project](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1279):

> Enabling asynchronous execution of database operations is actually
> orthogonal to enabling concurrent execution on the same context. In
> the particular case of server scenarios, using concurrent access could
> affect scalability negatively as it would mean that in order to
> process a single request you would be spinning of an arbitrary number
> of different threads. All the threads would compete for resources such
> as memory with other threads necessary to server other concurrent
> requests.

Entity Framework Core [does not support this scenario either](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async).

> EF Core doesn't support multiple parallel operations being run on the same context instance. You should always wait for an operation to complete before beginning the next operation. This is typically done by using the await keyword on each async operation.

Comment: Upvote for accuracy, although I wish I could downvote the guy who wrote the Codeplex snippet. A good query is almost entirely a hit to the db, which in most cases is multi-CPU and in many cases networked. Throwing a bunch of parallel async calls to the db uses NO threads! http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html It should be trivial for EF to support this if all queries are .AsNoTracking(), but it still throws this exception.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini I'm pretty sure the last sentence is not in refernce to EF but to the SQL Server.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: What is the point of using .ToListAsync() as oppose to ,ToList() if you can't run them asynchronously?

Comment: @MIKE Well it **is** asynchronous ; it's just you can't run multiple asynchronous SQL operations in parallel. Asynchronous programming has multiple advantages on the server side: the first is _not_ better performances, it's _scalability_, which means you won't block a thread until the operation completion. Even if you can't run two SQL requests in parallel, it's still a great advantage. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/12673868

Comment: This is old, but the keyword is "operations", not necessarily "queries". Only things that are atomic (inserts, updates, deletes) cannot be run in parallel, because it can lead to inconsistent state. However selects, counts, etc. are 100% fine to be run in parallel.

Comment: @ChrisPratt In EF6, even queries cannot run in parallel. You just _cannot_ start multiple async operations (get, count, update, delete, insert...) at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Just a note, as mentioned by ken2k this is not allowed when using Entity Framework with MS SQL Server.  However, if you are using Entity Framework with Oracle, this is allowed.

Comment: Can you give a source for that? My impression was that EF internally is not capable of running multiple queries at the same time. This would require its internal structures such as the identity map to be thread safe.

Comment: I can't give a source all I can say is that I have code running in production that uses that method.

Comment: Fingers crossed your pager will not go off at night. Thanks for reporting this.

Comment: A context is not thread-safe, never. The database provider doesn't have any influence. This is plainly wrong information.

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to update that with EF 5 it's now possible to split queries that load navigation properties in separate queries:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries

Still not solving your case but might be useful to know.

Comment: This is not related to parallel processing and therefore not relevant to mention here.