# Multiple Async Methods, best to use WhenAll with different return types

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have an Async controller action method which calls 4 async methods on my Backend to return List from each.  The List of objects is different for each method. ie List List etc.

I have this working as so:

```
BizProvider bp = new BizProvider();
List<biz.Customer> custReturn = await bp.GetCustomerAsync();
List<biz.Account> acctReturn = await bp.GetAccountAsync();
...plus 2 more
List<object> returnArr = new List<object>();
returnArr.Add(custReturn);
returnArr.Add(acctReturn);  ...plus 2 more
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnArr);
```

Should I use `Task.WhenAll` because of multiple Tasks?

The example at the microsoft
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194874%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

All the Tasks return `List<int>`

So I used and abstract class and had all my list object types inherit from this.
and I changed the return type of my business object provider to return the List of abstract type
so now I can do:

```
var tasks1 = new List<Task<List<Biz.AbstractClass>>>();
tasks1.Add(bp.GetCustomerAsAbstractAsync());
tasks1.Add(bp.GetAccountAsAbstractAsync());
...plus 2 more
```

I then call
    var continuation = Task.WhenAll(tasks1);

this executes then the next line it gets to the `.Results` but then stops executing???

```
foreach (var result in continuation.Result)
                                       ^ stops here
```

further on I call

```
returnArrays.Add(result1);
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnArrays);
```

but these never get hit...I don't know why.
Perhaps I don't need a `WhenAll`, but then I am still curious what is going wrong.
perhaps I need an await on the specific functions, or invoke the Action somehow, as in the Microsoft link the functions are called inline.

```
Task.Run(async () => { x=x,etc...)
```

Edit 20150306 => adding more implementation details

```
CustMan cm = new CustMan(); 
List<object> returnArr = new List<object>();
var aTask = cm.GetCustomersAsync(); 
var bTask = cm.GetAccountsAsync(); 
await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);  
returnArr.Add(aTask.Result);//same for bTask <-- breakpoint never hits 
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnArr); 
//also .js ajax return method never comes back.

//in CustMan()
public async Task<List<biz.Customer>> GetCustomersAsync() {
    List<biz.Customer> custList = await (from contact in ObjectContextDb.GetData<da.ContactInfo>()//<--generic returns IQueryable
     join customerContact in ObjectContextDb.GetData<da.CustomerContact>() on contact.Id equals customerContact.ContactInfoID
     join customerOrg in ObjectContextDb.GetData<da.CustomerOrganisation>() on customerContact.OrgID equals customerOrg.Id
     orderby contact.LastName
     select new biz.Customer {
       CustomerContactInfo = new biz.Contact() {
         ID = contact.Id,
         WorkPhone = contact.WorkPhone
       },
       CustomerOrg = new biz.CustomerOrganisation {
         ID = facultyOrg.Id,
         Name = facultyOrg.OrgName,
         ClientID = (customerContact.ClientID.HasValue ? customerContact.ClientID.Value : 0)
       }
     }).ToListAsync<biz.Customer>();
    return custList;// <-- Breakpoint hits here, the List has items
}

public async Task<List<biz.Account>> GetAccountsAsync()
{
 var roles = (from acctType in ObjectContextDb.GetData<da.AccountInType>()
  join r in ObjectContextDb.GetData<da.AccountType>() on acctType.AccountTypeID equals r.ID
  select new
  {
   AccountId = acctType.AccountID,
   Type = r.TypeName
  });   //.ToList();

  List<biz.Account> allContacts = await (from account in ObjectContextDb.GetData<da.Account>()
       orderby account.Name
       select new biz.Account()
       {
         Number = account.Id,
         Name = account.Name,
         Roles = (from r in roles where account.Id == r.AccountId select r.Type).ToList()
       }).ToListAsync<biz.Account>();

  return allContacts;//  <-- Breakpoint hits here, the List has items
}
```

The method which calls the Manager Class methods without `WhenAll` works!

```
CustMan cm = new CustMan(); 
List<object> returnArrays = new List<object>();
List<biz.Customer> custReturn = await cm.GetCustomersAsync();
List<biz.Account> acctReturn = await cm.GetAccountsAsync();

returnArrays.Add(custReturn);
returnArrays.Add(acctReturn);

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnArrays);
```

Comment: You can invoke `.GetAllFacultyAsync()` and `.GetAllContactsWithRolesAsync()` and await them later as well. This will kick off all async requests, but awaits them later, keeping them strongly typed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Task.WhenAll` without changing anything. Just store the tasks in a variable and add their results afterwards:

```
var aTask = GetAAsync();
var bTask = GetBAsync();
...
await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);
returnArr.Add(aTask.Result);
returnArr.Add(bTask.Result);
```

In you case however, the async operations use Entity Framework which [doesn't support multiple operations concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24702369/885318) so you can't do that.

Call and await your operations one at a time:

```
returnArr.Add(await GetAAsync());
returnArr.Add(await GetBAsync());  
...
```

Comment: I tried this but if I put a breakpoint after the await it never gets hit, and the ajax call that hits the action method which invokes this never returns.

Comment: @magister then your tasks never complete.  Show the code for them.

Comment: var aTask = cm.GetCustomersAsync();  
var bTask = cm.GetAccountsAsync();                                                        //above CustMan cm = new CustMan();                                                           List<object> returnArr = new List<object>();                                            await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);                                                            returnArr.Add(aTask.Result);//same for bTask  <-- breakpoint never hits                                 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnArr); //also .js ajax return never comes

Comment: @magister then your async method never complete. Show the code for them and we can tell you why.

Comment: I put it above but it didn't format correctly. If I answer my own question maybe I can show a better formatted view, but I am not answering it.

Comment: @magister You should add it to the question. However what you've added isn't the code for the async methods themselves, only for using them.

Comment: ok finally got the spaces right.  so you can see what is going on in the Manager class async methods.  Both of them get the results.  I will also add the method which works without WhenAll

Comment: @magister what's `ObjectContextDb`?

Comment: EntityFramework 6.0 with .NET 4.5 instead of DBContext using ObjectContext.

Comment: @magister EF doesn't support concurrent operations. Don't use `Task.WhenAll`. `await` each operation separately.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're doing this:

```
var continuation = Task.WhenAll(tasks1);
foreach (var result in continuation.Result) { }
```

Which is probably [deadlocking](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). `WhenAll` returns a `Task` too, so you'll need to `await` that:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks1);
foreach (var result in results) { }
```

Otherwise, building a `List` of tasks and passing them into `WhenAll` is a perfectly reasonable way to await multiple tasks concurrently.

Comment: oh jez, I missed that

Comment: do you know if I put a breakpoint after foreach....will it get hit?  I get to that point, no exceptions, but then I get pushed out to Acquire_RequestState in global.asax.cs