# Call multiple stored procedures using Async/Await and EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asynchronous, async-await

I have to call multiple stored procedures that consume time. Ideally those procedures have to exec in the same time but it raise lot of problems.

Here is the simplified code :

```
private  async void refresh_Controle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@devicename", DeviceName);
    Task<int> mcResult = GenkaiBase.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec Refresh_McAfee @devicename", param1);
    int Mc = await mcResult;

    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@devicename", DeviceName);

    Task<int> dcaiResult = GenkaiBase.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec Refresh_DCAI @devicename", param2);
    int Dc = await dcaiResult;
}
```

This has 2 issues:

1. those procedure execute one after the other
2. if I call this more than once, I get a SQL Server error where one of the procedure is chosen as victim.

I tried calling the two procedures in the same time with this code in an async method:

```
public async Task<bool> Refresh_Control(string devicename)
{
    List<Task> Tlist = new List<Task>();
    Console.WriteLine("Launch Refresh");

    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@devicename", devicename);

    Task<int> mcResult =  Genkai_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec Refresh_McAfee @devicename", param1);

    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@devicename", devicename);

    Task<int> dcaiResult =  Genkai_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec Refresh_DCAI @devicename", param2);

    Console.WriteLine("all set");

    Tlist.Add(mcResult);
    Tlist.Add(dcaiResult);

    await Task.WhenAll(Tlist.ToArray());
    int mc = await mcResult;
    int dc = await dcaiResult;

    Console.WriteLine("Finish Refresh" + mc + dc);
    return true;
}
```

The logic is fine for send thing simultaneous but the second procedure throw an error cause the first one isn't finish yet.

Error translated by goole:

> > An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional Information: A second operation was started in this context
>   before a previous asynchronous operation has been completed. Use
>   "await" to ensure that all asynchronous operations were completed
>   before calling another method in this context. No member instance is
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.

So what is the deal, why can't I call several stored procedures at the same time without being stuck by SQL Server?

Comment: entity framework you can't, you can with multiple context, but I guess you can do this with normal ADO.NET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

I believe that this is simply not supported by EF at this point in time, and perhaps this is a duplicate question based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702183/does-entity-framework-support-parallel-async-queries).  It cannot be done... Sorry.

**Original**

The issue is that you are trying to `await` them twice.  When you pass them into the `await Task.WhenAll` function they are running in parallel and awaited.  Then afterwards you are then trying to await them again, instead of access the `.Result` of the task instance.

Please try the code below and let me know if it works.

```
public async Task Refresh_Control(string devicename)
{
    Task<int> mcResult = 
        Genkai_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec Refresh_McAfee @devicename", 
            new SqlParameter("@devicename", devicename));
    Task<int> dcaiResult = 
        Genkai_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("exec Refresh_DCAI @devicename", 
            new SqlParameter("@devicename", devicename));

    await Task.WhenAll(mcResult, dcaiResult);

    int mc = mcResult.Result;
    int dc = dcaiResult.Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Finish Refresh :: mc=" + mc + ", dc=" + dc);
}
```

Comment: It raise the same error than my second exemple at line start with Task<int> dcaiResult = . (see the error in main post ) .a cmd is already launched i have to wait before exec a seconde one???

Comment: await does not run tasks, it waits for tasks already running. At the time Task.WhenAll is hin both tasks are already running.

Comment: yes and the error is not on the await its rigth at line that exec the second procedure. Its ether EF or SQL server that reject the exec.But  i doubt it have no fix to this.

Comment: @David you confirm its EF limit so mean i can parallele  with let say ADO? i know it raise sql probleme too but if i have just to deal with deadlock than this limite it maybe better to use ADO .

Comment: @Zwan Yes, the limitation is with EF. EF is throwing the exception, straight-up ADO.NET would allow you to do both in parallel.  Please mark my answer as "accepted" if you find it to be correct.  Thank you

Comment: @DavidPine I guess await Task.WhenAll is the place OP is having problem

Comment: @brykneval, that is where the symptom of the problem shows itself -- as the invocation of the asynchronous calls will then throw as EF detects that you're attempting two calls in parallel.