# Entity framework - queue async context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

```
    Task task1 = serviceA.DoSomething();
    Task task2 = serviceB.DoSomethingElse();

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Services have no idea that they are operating on database, however if both tasks end up querying one database there will be concurrency exception.

As described in [Does Entity Framework support parallel async queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702183/does-entity-framework-support-parallel-async-queries) EF does not support multiple async queries.

Is there pattern or some way to queue such queries/commands and execute them one after another (but still speed up execuition if they are hitting separate database)?

Maybe better solution would be to change dbContext from per-request to transient and new up dbContext with separate connection for each query? What are performance implications of this?
First that I see is separate transaction for each dbcontext and commiting them all instead of single transaction.