# IEnumerable Query with ContinueWith: Order of completion guarantee?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, order-of-execution

I have an input array that I need to produce an output that is in the same order. If I run

```
source.Select((item, index) =>
  remoteDb.Where(condition).FirstOrDefaultAsync()
    .ContinueWith(result -> /* Manipulate and save to outArray */));
```

Do I have any guarantee that `ContinueWith()` will execute in the same order as the source array? Basically, can I save with `outArray.append(result)`, or will I need to use `outArray[index] = result` to save it in the appropriate order?

Comment: When you tested it, what did you observe?

Comment: I really doubt it will be in your desired order by default. I tried something similar. But this LINQ-Query should be optimized. This doesn't look healthy.

Comment: The tasks will be created in the order of the input array, but there is absolutely no guarantee they will complete in that order. If remoteDb is something like Entity Framework, then it [won't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24702183/11683).

Comment: @GSerg: Yeah, the error predicted in the top answer is exactly what I'm seeing: `A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed.` I've stripped out the `ContinueWith()` and am trying it with just `outArray = Select( => Where().FirstOrDefaultAsync()).ToArray();` Hoping that gives me what I need.

Comment: No, it won't. It's the `.FirstOrDefaultAsync` that does it, not the `.ContinueWith`. Just use the non-async `.FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Side note: ideally you just keep such crazy ideas of mixing all ways to make code asynchronous to your privately used code... There is very small number of people who can reason about mixing Tasks, await, and ContinueWith and even less who get it right. I'd strongly recommend sticking with far more common `await` and `Task.WhenAll`....

Comment: And it turns out that even there I have to use the synchronous version of `FirstOrDefault`. I couldn't find anywhere to put my `async` and `await` to work with the async version.

Comment: Which apparently SO didn't notify me you had already told me.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Actually, this was all wrapped in a `WhenAll`; I just didn't include it in the question because it didn't seem relevant to what was happening, as it never even got touched. And now it's gone.

Comment: You cannot use WhenAll with EF. It just not thread safe.

Comment: @Trevortni - You could `await` the `.FirstOrDefault` with `Task.Run(() => ... )` if you want to push it to a task, but keep the order.