# Best way to parallelize .NET tasks with Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, parallel-processing, task

I have a program which needs to execute the following instructions:

1. Retrieve via a Http request a list of items
2. For every retrieved item, execute another Http request with that item as parameter

For now, my solution is the following:

```cs
var items = await _repository.GetItems(someInt, someGuid);
var itemsUpdated = new ConcurrentDictionary<Item, ConcurrentDictionary<Dto,TransactionType>>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    _ = itemsUpdated.TryAdd(item, 
        (await _updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someInt, someGuid, item))!);
}
```

In my application, I use Task.WhenAll() in numerous places to paralellize tasks to improve performance. I just don't see how I can use it here.

I have tried the following but get stuck:

```cs
var items = await _repository.GetItems(someInt, someGuid);
var itemsUpdated = new ConcurrentDictionary<Item, ConcurrentDictionary<Dto,TransactionType>>();

var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(_updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someInt, someGuid, item));

    //_ = itemsUpdated.TryAdd(item, 
    //    (await _updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someInt, someGuid, item))!);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
// how to get the updatedItems from the tasks and insert
// by item in the itemsUpdated ConcurrentDictionary
```

Also, since we are speaking about improving performance; while initializing the ConcurrentDictionary, I wish to pass the expected length to avoid a re-initialization of the backing array. However, the constructors also asks for a number of threads expected to execute on the ConcurrentDictionary. I have no idea what to use here. Of course this depends on the solution that is used to parallelize the tasks.

Comment: Does it _have to be_ `Task.WhenAll` ?

Comment: Are you sure your repository supports several in-flight tasks at once? E.g. Entity Framework [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24702183/11683).

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rJU1xB? But be aware that not everything supports _concurrent_ access while providing an async API.

Comment: If the steps are a combination of Http API call and persisting the result, then maybe parallize Network-API calls in batches and then write each batch in bulk while concurrently fetching the next batch?

Comment: Have you considered using the .NET 6 [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API?

Comment: @GSerg it does, in this case both are backed by a HttpClient, but everywhere else I use async Dapper calls.

Comment: @Fildor It does not, but this would keep consistency in the application.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias interesting! I can somewhat imagine how a solution like this would work but could you maybe create an answer with Parallel.ForEachAsync?

Comment: Stijn you can find a `Parallel.ForEachAsync` example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136542/parallel-foreach-with-asynchronous-lambda/68901782#68901782 "Parallel foreach with asynchronous lambda"). If you also want to collect the results, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907650/foreachasync-with-result/71129678#71129678 "ForEachAsync with Result").

Comment: @TheodorZoulias great, thanks! This is perfect. I will make this the preferred answer unless you want to add it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my application, I use Task.WhenAll() in numerous places to parallelize tasks to improve performance. I just don't see how I can use it here.

One common solution is to use LINQ (specifically, `Select` with an asynchronous delegate) to map some items to some sequence of tasks, and then just `Task.WhenAll` that:

```
var items = await _repository.GetItems(someInt, someGuid);

var tasks = items
    .Select(item => _updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someInt, someGuid, item))
    .ToList();

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

`results` will contain an array with all the task results (whatever `AsyncGetChangedEntities` returns).

I don't see any need for concurrent data structures with the code as provided. However, if you need a concurrent dictionary for some reason, the following should work:

```
var items = await _repository.GetItems(someInt, someGuid);

var tasks = items
    .Select(async item => new KeyValuePair<Item, ConcurrentDictionary<Dto,TransactionType>>(
        item,
        await _updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someInt, someGuid, item)))
    .ToList();

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var itemsUpdated = new ConcurrentDictionary<Item, ConcurrentDictionary<Dto,TransactionType>>(results);
```

Comment: You're right that the concurrent data structures are not required in this example, but other code requires it.

Comment: How can I insert the items into the updatedItems dictionary in your answer. I now get a List of items instead of a dictionary of updatedItems.

Comment: @StijnWingens: If the result has to be a concurrent dictionary, then you can change the `Select` to `Select(async item => new KeyValuePair<Item, ...>(item, await _updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someInt, someGuid, item)))` and pass the resulting list to the dictionary constructor.

Comment: Could you edit the answer so it does return the a concurrent dict?

Comment: @StijnWingens: Done.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var items = await _repository.GetItems();

var itemsUpdated = new ConcurrentDictionary<Item, ConcurrentDictionary<Dto, TransactionType>>(concurrencyLevel: Environment.ProcessorCount,  capacity: items.Length);

async Task<KeyValue> InvokeTask(Item item)
   {
      var value = await _updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someint, someGuid, item);
      itemsUpdated.TryAdd(item, value);
      return  new() {Key = item, Value = value};
   }
        
var tasks = items.Select(InvokeTask)
                 .ToArray(); //Tasks will be created here

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks); //Wait for them to complete and collect the results
```

You can create some function to wrap your async call, so that you will get `Task<T>` and will not have to cast result into `T` explicitly.

`KeyValue` type may be something like this:

```cs
public struct KeyValue
    {
        public Item Key;
        public ConcurrentDictionary<Dto, TransactionType> Value;
    }
```

You may pass `items.Length` as `capacity` and `Environment.ProccessorCount` (this value is used by default) as `concurrencyLevel` into the `ConcurrentDictionary` constructor.

Comment: When `tasks` are `Task<TResult>`, then [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-whenall-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-threading-tasks-task((-0)))))) already returns `Task<TResult[]>`

Comment: @Fildor, thanks, I've corrected my answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thanks also for the Environment.ProcessorCount info too!

Answer (score 0):

I like your original code.

Could you try the code below (using `Task.Run`) ? I'm not as good as others into performance tuning, I hope you will get good performance:

```cs
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run( () => {
      _ = itemsUpdated.TryAdd(item, 
          (await _updateRepository.AsyncGetChangedEntities(someInt, someGuid, item))
          );
    });
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Task.Run is not preferable to await. Also, this does not parallelize the tasks. They still run sequentially